# Network communication with CP443-1EX11

Tags: c++, networking, tcp, communication, plc

What is needed to implement a TCP-communication via Fetch/Write to a Siemens S7 PLC with the **CP443-1EX11** network processor on the PC side (Windows, C++) using two TCP and two ISO-on-TCP connections?

Comment: Just found a [link](http://www.sps-forum.de/hochsprachen-opc/5162-c-winsock-iso-tcp-sps-telegrammen.html) but it is in german. So the only thing I got from this that the Fetch/Write principle is a kind of polling where I actually access a data block. Furthermore the post says that there has to be a documentation but I can't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a short google search and you can find [information](http://support.automation.siemens.com/WW/llisapi.dll?func=cslib.csinfo&objId=23592043&nodeid4=20229805&load=content&lang=de&siteid=cseus&aktprim=4&objaction=csview&extranet=standard&viewreg=WW) at the Siemens web page. The web page links a [FETCH/WRITE documentation PDF](http://cache.automation.siemens.com/dnl/TA/TA0Mjg0NQAA_23592043_Tools/23592043_FetchWrite_PNCPU_v22_e.pdf).

Comment: I was many times at the siemens online support page, but didn't find that pdf. Thanks alot. U made my day.

Comment: As far as I've understood (just skimmed through) the documentation is exactly what I need. I'm going to implement the communication-protocol and test it and will give an additional feedback as soon as possible. Thanks alot.